# Exception thrown when creating a website via Invoke-Command

Tags: iis, powershell

I'm calling the command

```
Invoke-Command  -computername remotepc { 
Import-Module WebAdministration; 
New-Website -Name www.somesite.com -ApplicationPool www.somesite.com -hostHeader www.somesite.com -physicalPath c:\inetpub\wwwroot }
```

The website is created successfully in IIS on the remote machine. However an exception message is displayed when powershell returns:

```
Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Website], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.NewWebsite
   Command
```

Does anyone know why I'm receiving this message and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you try :

```
$var = New-Website ...
```

Not sure but `New-Website` return an object that PowerShell remote session try to serialize unsuccesfully.